# Identifying database errors and query errors separate in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am writing a RESTful web service using spring 3 and I noticed that when I implemented my DAO's (I am using spring-jdbc for database access), the exceptions that get thrown are pretty generic, so i am not able to identify if the exception occurred because my database is down or my query failed.

sample code:

```
try {
    Q q = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(MY_QUERY, new Object[]{id}, new MyMapper());
    return q;
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    // What is this exception ? database down ? query failed ?
}
```

Unless I know what exception is this during runtime, I can't send back reasonable error message to service client.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the exact exception? Can you provide the exception stack trace?

Comment: There are multiple exceptions and I know why they happen, but I want to know it at runtime to provide proper message to end user. Currently I am handling one kind of exceptions by using "instanceof" inside my catch block and adding a different message to error I am returning, i am not sure how many of those instanceof's I need to handle all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to catch every single possible exception; code so that you don't run into the possibility of multiple user or programmer error type exceptions. Generally there are three type of exceptions that occur in every DAO regardless of what you do. (1) your database is down... imo if this is the issue you've got bigger problems. (2) user authentication error which is easy enough to catch and deal with (however you should probably be handling that situation on your RESTful front-end. (3) improper data. If you have bad data, just send the attempted data back and the reason for the exception.

```
try {
    Q q = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(MY_QUERY, new Object[]{id}, new MyMapper());
    return q;
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    throw new DaoException("Could not retrieve q with ID: " + qID, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `queryForObject` only throws `DataAccessException` or `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`. You shouldn't catch exception due to database connection failure at this level. However, in your DAO class, you normally have code to establish the dataSource which can be injected by Spring's IoC container. That part of code will throw exception if the database connection fails. You should catch DB failure exception there.